# Too soon to pass the IATRA exam? (Canada)

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, pilot-certification, flight-school, type-ratings

I just finished the IFR group 1 rating this week. Currently at 220h Total flight time with CPL, no job in sight (of course), and wondering if I should start studying for the IATRA now or wait until I'm closer to 250h and/or a job?

Thanks in advance, have a delicious day!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time on your hands might as well get started with the study part.  IATRA is the ATPLs condensed into a single smaller 50 question exam.  You will expand your knowledge base and it never hurts to acquire knowledge sooner rather than later.

Don't take the exam right away though, as it is only good for 2 years and it might be a lot longer than that before you'll land a job that needs a multi-crew qualification.  There's a lot of pilots on furlough and it's going to be several years for the industry to reabsorb them all.  Most of the opportunities are going to be in the North.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'd like to pay for the course only once when I'll decide to pass the exam. Might still end up buying it early though!